# An international Riley riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge, affix-riddle

A simple Riley riddle. Watch the tags!

> My prefix feels not so lucky in Rome.
> My infix denotes the Third Rome.
> My suffix plays in the brass band.
> My whole created a new country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> **1776** - the year the US declared independence from the British Empire. (*'My whole created a new country.'*)

*My prefix feels not so lucky in Rome.*

> The number **17** is considered unlucky in Italy - a notion that dates back to [Ancient Roman times](https://anamericaninrome.com/wp/2020/04/why-17-is-unlucky-in-italy/).

*My infix denotes the Third Rome.*

> '[The Third Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow,_third_Rome)' is often considered to be the Russian capital, Moscow. One of the region numbers for Moscow that appears on [Russian license plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Russia) is **77**.

*My suffix plays in the brass band.*

> This is a reference to the song '[**SEVENTY-SIX** Trombones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventy-Six_Trombones)', a song whose [lyrics](https://genius.com/Meredith-willson-seventy-six-trombones-lyrics) revolve around a *brass band*.

Put these all together (with overlap), and we have:

> the year **1776**! The [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag here leads us to the use of *numbers* rather than words in this puzzle, and the *international* flavour of the lines (via references to Italy and Moscow) ties in nicely with the significance of the year in the [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_States_(1776%E2%80%931789)) of another country - the United States of America...

Comment: Great! You were quick.

Comment: @trolley813 Ha, thanks :) I had the suffix straight away (with tags in mind), deduced the prefix and just had to spend some time convincing myself that the infix satisfied the line somehow! A *lot* of Googling then ensued...!